# CPU Time spent for each sql server session using DMVs?

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-performance, dmv

Is there a way to get the CPU Time for each session or for every open connection in SQL Server 2005 using DMVs? I have kind of tried various combinations of  sys.dm_exec_query_stats, sys.dm_exec_connections, sys.dm_exec_sessions. Am i missing some other obvious way to get this same information? My environment is a SQL Server 2005 with about 100 databases where one database takes about 40% CPU (found using query below) and I am trying to figure out whats (number of connections, what queries, etc..) is taking it upto 40%.

This script gives CPU time for each Database. I just need to break it down to Session OR at least at the Connection level.

```
WITH DB_CPU_Stats
AS
(SELECT DatabaseID, DB_Name(DatabaseID) AS [DatabaseName], 
  SUM(total_worker_time) AS [CPU_Time_Ms]
 FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(int, value) AS [DatabaseID] 
              FROM sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(qs.plan_handle)
              WHERE attribute = N'dbid') AS F_DB
 GROUP BY DatabaseID)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [CPU_Time_Ms] DESC) AS [row_num],
       DatabaseName, [CPU_Time_Ms], 
       CAST([CPU_Time_Ms] * 1.0 / SUM([CPU_Time_Ms]) 
       OVER() * 100.0 AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [CPUPercent]
FROM DB_CPU_Stats
WHERE DatabaseID > 4 -- system databases
AND DatabaseID <> 32767 -- ResourceDB
ORDER BY row_num
```

Appreciate if you could provide a working sample.

**UPDATE:**

Modified the query above - Is this good enough? Just want someone to validate...

```
WITH DB_CPU_Stats
AS
(SELECT DatabaseID, DB_Name(DatabaseID) AS [DatabaseName], sql_handle,
  SUM(total_worker_time) AS [CPU_Time_Ms]
 FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(int, value) AS [DatabaseID] 
              FROM sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(qs.plan_handle)
              WHERE attribute = N'dbid') AS F_DB
 GROUP BY DatabaseID, sql_handle
)


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [CPU_Time_Ms] DESC) AS [row_num],
       DatabaseName, [CPU_Time_Ms],  text, count(1) as Connections,
       CAST([CPU_Time_Ms] * 1.0 / SUM([CPU_Time_Ms]) 
       OVER() * 100.0 AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [CPUPercent]
FROM DB_CPU_Stats
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) C
join sys.dm_exec_connections CON on CON.most_recent_sql_handle = sql_handle
WHERE DatabaseID > 4 -- system databases
AND DatabaseID <> 32767 -- ResourceDB
GROUP BY CPU_Time_Ms, DatabaseName, text
ORDER BY row_num
```

Is the most_recent_handle of dm_exec_connections, supposed to map to sql_handle of dm_exec_query_text?